# import error in sublime

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, sublimetext3

I am using python 2.7 and I want to use a package named `pysrt`. My program works nice in idle but in sublime I have the following error when I type :

```
import pysrt
```

The error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\t.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pysrt
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\pysrt.py", line 1
    Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You appear to have copied the Python version string into your source file. It'll not work in IDLE either; this is not a Sublime-only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sublime works with the path variable in your computer. Maybe you have changed the path, or somthing simillar happens. Or maybe you have a file named pysrt and the importation of the module failed because of the same name.